# prove existence of limit $\sum n/2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to prove  limit  exist. i have to do it by the Cauchy criterion $|a_m-a_n| <\epsilon$.

Here is my attempt:
$$|a_m-a_n|=\left|\sum_{m=n+1}^m \frac{n}{2^n}\right|$$
and now i try to increase the expression but everything i try make it too high.

i recognize that $$\frac{n}{2^n} >\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$$ and then increase the expression by changing all of it to $n/2^n$ is not helping.

if you have other option,without Cauchy,or how to make my way better,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ and $S_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$.  Then note that
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{2n}\cdot\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{n+1}{2n}a_n=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)a_n.
$$
In particular, for $n\geq 2$, we see that
$$
a_{n+1}\leq\frac{3}{4}a_n.
$$
So, as a result, for $2\leq m\leq M$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert S_M-S_m\rvert&=\sum_{n=m+1}^{M}a_n\\
&\leq a_{m+1}+\frac{3}{4}a_{m+1}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2a_{m+1}+\cdots\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{M-m-1}a_{m+1}\\
&=a_{m+1}\left[1+\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{M-m-1}\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Notice that the quantity in brackets is bounded above the by geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}=4.
$$
So, for any $m\leq M$, we have
$$
\lvert S_M-S_m\rvert\leq4a_{m+1}=4\cdot\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}.
$$
Clearly, you can make this 'sufficiently small' by making $m$ large enough. So, by filling in some further details, you can use the Cauchy criteria as you requested.

However, that being said, it is... a weird way to do this.  Because this exact same argument shows that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ converges by comparison.  Or, if you don't feel you have the 'comparison test' yet, it converges because the sequence of partial sums is monotone inreasing and bounded above.

Comment: Thank you very much!! can you tell me please how you write in math in the browser?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Try the ratio test.
$$
\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^{n}}{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
\cdot\frac{1}{2}\to \frac{1}{2}<1.
$$
Therefore, the series converges.

Comment: Hey thanks, it looks so easy.

Comment: i need to do it for the sum,it doesnt mean the sum going to zero.

Comment: The ratio test implies that the sum converges. It does not converge to $0$, but it converges to some finite number.

Comment: ok thanks, but we i cant use it in my homework because we didn't prove such a thing yet,can you give me another way?

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}...\frac{n}{2^n}$$
$$2S=1+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{2^2}...$$
$$S=\qquad \qquad \; \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}...$$
So $2S-S= 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}...=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2$

Comment: Through algebraic manipulation it can be made geometric, this can be done for any sum n/(a^n)

Comment: I didn't read your details closely enough. Sorry for my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{2^k}$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $N$ so that for any $n\ge N$ we have $\frac{n+2}{2^n}<\varepsilon.$ Then for any $m>n\ge N$ we have
$$
\lvert S_m-S_n \rvert=\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{k}{2^k}<\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{k}{2^k}.
$$

Now let $T=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{k}{2^k}$ and using the same kind of algebraic manipulation @Teh Rod used we get
$$
\begin{align*}
2T&=\frac{n+1}{2^{n}}+\frac{n+2}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{n+3}{2^{n+2}}+\frac{n+4}{2^{n+3}}+\cdots\\
-T&=\qquad~-\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}-\frac{n+3}{2^{n+1}}-\cdots\\\hline
T&=\frac{n+1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}~+\,\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}~~+\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left(1+\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot 2\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\\
&=\frac{n+2}{2^n}.
\end{align*}
$$
Thus when $n\ge N$ we have
$$
\lvert S_m-S_n \rvert<T=\frac{n+2}{2^n}<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: as i understand the manipulation ,you take the 2st number from 2s and subtract it from the 1st number in S , and further more.

Comment: i cant understand what happend with the last number in 2s.

Comment: I'll edit to improve clarity...

Comment: thanks but my question is,2T sum until m/(2^(m-1)) and sum T is until m/(2^m) and how do we subtract the "last" number? i cant understand just that.

Comment: i mean the last number of T

Comment: T is the summation from n+1 to infinity. That is to say T has no last term in the summation. The partial sum from n+1 to m is going to be strictly less than T and T is a lot easier to work with than the partial sum from n+1 to m.